# Finding triangles where the coordinates of vertices, centroid, orthocenter and circumcenter are all integers

Tags: geometry

I am trying to find all triangles that satisfy the following conditions:

1. Each vertex `{x, y}` is a pair of integers such that -20 <= x, y <= 20.
2. The coordinates of the centroid, circumcenter and orthocenter are also pairs of integers.

First, I find some triples `i1, g1,h1`

```
Clear[i1, g1, h1];
g1 = {x1, y1};
h1 = {x2, y2};
i1 = {x3, y3};
ss = {g1, h1, i1} /. 
   Solve[{h1 - i1 == 3 (g1 - i1), 
     Sequence @@ Thread[0 < {x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3} < 8]}, {x1, y1, 
     x2, y2, x3, y3}, Integers];
list = Select[ss, 
  6 == Length[Union @@ #1] && Times @@ Union @@ #1 != 0 &]
```

> {{{2, 5}, {4, 3}, {1, 6}}, {{3, 4}, {7, 2}, {1, 5}}, {{3, 6}, {5, 
>      4}, {2, 7}}, {{4, 3}, {2, 7}, {5, 1}}, {{4, 5}, {6, 1}, {3, 
>      7}}, {{5, 2}, {3, 4}, {6, 1}}, {{5, 4}, {1, 6}, {7, 3}}, {{6, 
>      3}, {4, 5}, {7, 2}}}

With `g = list[[1]][[1]];
h = list[[1]][[2]];`

I inputed

```
g = list[[1]][[1]];
h = list[[1]][[2]];
a = {x1, y1};
b = {x2, y2};
c = {x3, y3};
sols = Solve[{x1 + x2 + x3 == 3 g[[1]], 
    y1 + y2 + y3 == 3 g[[2]], (h - a).(c - b) == 0, (h - b).(c - a) ==
      0, Sequence @@ Thread[-20 < {x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3} < 20], 
    x2 y3 - x1 y3 + x1 y2 - y2 x3 + y1 x3 - y1 x2 != 0}, {x1, y1, x2, 
    y2, x3, y3}, Integers];
{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}} /. sols;
result = Union[Sort /@ %];
Clear[pA, pB, pC, h, t];
Table[{pA, pB, pC} = points;
 h = {m, n};
 t = {x, y};
 sol = Solve[{(h - pA). (pB - pC) == 0, (h - pB) .(pA - pC) == 0}, {m,
     n}];
 orthocentre = {m, n} /. sol[[1]];
 g = (pA + pB + pC)/3;
 centre = Circumsphere[points][[1]];
 {pA, pB, pC, g, orthocentre, centre}, {points, result}]
```

How can I input all elements of `list` automatically?

Comment: Please remove the extra "x" from the second condition